# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "max_table"

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I want to get the maximum id from the home_history table and filtered home_history by this value. I used it with the operator. where did I mistake it?

```
with max_table as (select max(id) as max_id from home_history),
     current_data as (
         select Cast(created_at As date), count(id)
         from home_history
         where id > (max_table.max_id - 30 * 500000)
           and created_at >= CAST((now() + (INTERVAL '-30 day')) AS date)
           and home_history.created_at < CAST(now() AS date)
         group by CAST(created_at AS date)
         order by CAST(created_at As Date)
     )
SELECT *
from current_data;
```

> [42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "max_table"
> Position: 201

Comment: What the error message says: you don't have a reference to `max_table` in the `FROM` clause of the second CTE

Comment: try: select * from max_table. Because "current_data" is nested in the max_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is obvious to you, you have to explicitly state in your main query that you select from the CTE.

Think of a CTE as a view defined just for a single query. You'd need a `FROM` clause to indicate the view you select from.